# PHP Form from Array Select Value Edit/Save

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm using an array to output a form for product entry.

```
$labels = array(
    "category" => "Model",
    "model_number" => "Model No.",
    "description" => "Description");
```

The categories are populated as select/option set, which is easy when adding a new product. The issue comes when I need to edit the product. I would like to query the category table to return all the available categories to populate the select/option set. At the same time, I need to query the products table so that I can provide their saved Model Number and Description.

The following is my code from the add form to give you an idea of how I'm structuring this.

```
foreach($labels as $field => $label) {
        if($field == "category") {
            echo "<label>$label:</label>";
            echo "<select name=\"$field\">";
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                extract($row);
                echo "<option value=\"$category\">$category</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";
            echo "<br />";
        }
        else {
            echo "<label>$label:</label>";
            echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"$field\" />";
            echo "<br />";
        }
```

Thanks for the help. I'm sure it's simple, but my brain isn't quite providing me with the solution at the moment.

Comment: do you mean to say that a category has many products, and as soon as you select the category you want to list all the product belonging to that category? is `$labels` multi dimensional array. it will be helpful if you give more information.

Answer (score 0):

1. Having $labels array is a bad idea.
2. Get all your data first. Select your product data into array. Select your categories into array.
3. Show the form, as any other HTML you create with PHP

---

```
<label>Model:</label>
<select name="category">
<? foreach($cats as $category): ?>
  <option<? if ($category == $row['category'])?> selected?>><?=$category?></option>
<? endforeach ?>
</select>
<br />
<label>Model No.:</label>
<input type="text" name="model_number" value="<?=$row['model_number']?>"/>
<br />
```

and so on

don't forget to `htmlspecialchars()` your values before placing them into `value` attribute

Answer (score -1):

you can query the product table like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = $product_id";

$q = mysql_query( $sql );

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $q );

$model_number = $row['model_number'];

$description = $row['description'];

$category = $row['category'];
```